# How to get the cost details for a particular resource group from azure using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I am using the below code to get the list of resource groups. But I need to check the cost details for the resource groups coming up for each of them. Which module will support for this and what are the permissions needed in order to achieve it?

```
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
import requests

subscription_id = 'MYSUBID'
client_id = 'MYCLIENTID'
client_secret = 'MYSECRETVALUE'
tenant_id = 'MYTENANTID'

# Create a ClientSecretCredential object
credential = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id=tenant_id, client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret)

url = f"https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription_id}/resourcegroups?api-version=2021-04-01"
# Get an access token for the Azure Management API
access_token = credential.get_token("https://management.azure.com/.default")


# Make the GET request to retrieve a list of resource groups
headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

if response.status_code == 200:
    resource_groups = response.json()
    for rg in resource_groups['value']:
        print(rg['name'])
else:
    print(response.status_code, "-" ,response.text)
```

Comment: Do you need the output like [**this**](https://i.imgur.com/bO8L3Z1.png). I passed theparticular resource group to get the cost.

Comment: Yes @Rukmini I need the output exactly like the way you did

Comment: Okay Posting it as an answer. Do you need in INR or USD?

Comment: I need in USD @Rukmini

Comment: It would be great if you post for both. But at this point I need for USD @Rukmini

Answer (score 2):

**To get the cost details for a particular resource group from Azure using python in `USD`, use the below code:**

```py
import os
from datetime import *
from azure.mgmt.costmanagement import CostManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.costmanagement.models import QueryDefinition, QueryDataset, QueryTimePeriod, QueryAggregation, QueryGrouping 
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential

time_period_in_past=30
ResourceGroupName="ruk"
SubscriptionID="SubscriptionID"

maxDateInPast = ((datetime.now(timezone.utc))-timedelta(days=time_period_in_past))

credentials = ClientSecretCredential(
       tenant_id="TenantID",
       client_id="ClientID",
       client_secret="ClientSecret"
    )

time_period=QueryTimePeriod(from_property=maxDateInPast, to=datetime.now(timezone.utc))

client = CostManagementClient(credentials)

query_aggregation = dict()
query_aggregation["totalCost"] = QueryAggregation(name="Cost", function="Sum")
query_aggregation["totalCostUSD"] = QueryAggregation(name="CostUSD", function="Sum") 
query_grouping = [QueryGrouping(type="Dimension", name="ResourceId"), QueryGrouping(type="Dimension", name="ChargeType"),
                    QueryGrouping(type="Dimension", name="PublisherType")]

querydataset = QueryDataset(granularity=None, configuration=None, aggregation=query_aggregation, grouping=query_grouping)
query = QueryDefinition(type="ActualCost", timeframe="Custom", time_period=time_period, dataset=querydataset)
scope = f'/subscriptions/{SubscriptionID}/resourceGroups/{ResourceGroupName}'

result = client.query.usage(scope = scope, parameters=query)

cost_sum = 0
for row in result.as_dict()['rows']:
    cost_sum += row[1]
print(f"Cost for [{time_period_in_past}] days for resource group [{ResourceGroupName}] is [{cost_sum}] USD")
```

[image]

**To get the cost details for a particular resource group from Azure using python in `INR`, use the below code:**

```py
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone
from azure.mgmt.costmanagement import CostManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.costmanagement.models import QueryDefinition, QueryDataset, QueryTimePeriod, QueryAggregation, QueryGrouping
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential

time_period_in_past = 30
resource_group_name = "ruk"
exchange_rate_usd_to_inr = 83.16  # Replace with the actual exchange rate

maxDateInPast = ((datetime.now(timezone.utc)) - timedelta(days=time_period_in_past))

credentials = ClientSecretCredential(
    tenant_id='TenantID',
    client_id='ClientID',
    client_secret='ClientSecret'
)

time_period = QueryTimePeriod(from_property=maxDateInPast, to=datetime.now(timezone.utc))

client = CostManagementClient(credentials)

query_aggregation = {
    "totalCost": QueryAggregation(name="Cost", function="Sum"),
    "totalCostUSD": QueryAggregation(name="CostUSD", function="Sum")
}

query_grouping = [QueryGrouping(type="Dimension", name="ResourceId"), QueryGrouping(type="Dimension", name="ChargeType"),
                  QueryGrouping(type="Dimension", name="PublisherType")]

querydataset = QueryDataset(granularity=None, configuration=None, aggregation=query_aggregation, grouping=query_grouping)
query = QueryDefinition(type="ActualCost", timeframe="Custom", time_period=time_period, dataset=querydataset)
scope = f'/subscriptions/SubscriptionID/resourceGroups/{resource_group_name}'

result = client.query.usage(scope=scope, parameters=query)

cost_sum = 0
for row in result.as_dict()['rows']:
    cost_sum += row[1]

# Convert the cost from USD to INR
cost_sum_in_inr = cost_sum * exchange_rate_usd_to_inr

print(f"Cost for [{time_period_in_past}] days for resource group [{resource_group_name}] is [{cost_sum_in_inr}] INR")
```

[image]

> **Note** that: Assign **`Reader`** role to the service principal to fetch the data.

[image]

Comment: Perfect it works well for resource group level, What to do if we need to get cost for Resource level instead of resource group level ?